Do we really apply both single-qubit and two-qubit gates in the same layer in experiments?
I'm doing experiments using superconducting computers, and my question is as follows:

Performing quantum gates requires isolating the coupling between a target qubit and other neighboring qubits.
To implement a CZ gate, biasing the qubits is necessary to align the frequencies of the two qubits.
Applying a bias to any individual qubit will alter the cutoff point of nearby couplers.
Therefore, when two qubits are involved in a CZ gate, it affects the cutoff points of neighboring couplers.
If nearby qubits are simultaneously subjected to single-qubit gates while these two qubits are performing a CZ gate, they will be influenced by the behavior of these two qubits.
Typically, we will design separate patterns for two-qubit gates, and single-qubit gates are not placed in the same layer as two-qubit gates to prevent interference.

However, in quantum circuits constructed by Qiskit, Circ or other popular tools, single-qubit gates and two-qubit gates can always appear on the same layer. In actual experiments, given a circuit containing both single-qubit and two-qubit gates in the same layer, can IBM (or Google's) quantum computers do those gates in the same layer when executing instructions ? Or will it be executed in different layers in actual situations?
A simple example:


"3. Applying a bias to any individual qubit will alter the cutoff point of nearby couplers." - this sounds like one of several effects referred to as "crosstalk". The answer depends on the severity of crosstalk compared to the additional decoherence incurred by spreading out gates in time. Anecdotally, I did process tomography once on the same circuit with different amounts of staggering (spreading out parallel gates over n>1 time steps), and running gates in parallel was always a clear winner.

Thx for your good comment! But actually I don't mean the shift of coupling strength here is caused by noise or 'crosstalk'. We use tunable coupler in our group, so the coupling strength changes with the frequency of both qubits coupled to it. The unexpected shift of coupling strength will greatly affect the fidelity of the parallel gates. However, for those who use couplers with fixed frequency, I think the comparison indeed makes sense.
I'd like to see how other groups handles this problem. Thank you again!
